# Is there some ways to make some drawings connnected to each other?

Tags: google-drawings

Let's say I have drawn a series of graphs about manga creation. Every graph is about a single topic of that kind, and it's on a single drawing file. Now I want to make these graphs interconnected in some way according to their pattern similarity or logical correlation.

Is there something like a tag function to organize these files?